# program terminating while executing

Tags: c, file, terminate

This C program is compiling successfully without errors:

```
int main(){   
    char file1[100];  
    int count=0; 
    char c,ch,ck;

    FILE *fptr;
    printf("Enter the file name\n"); 
    scanf("%s", file1);

    fptr=fopen(file1, "r"); 
    printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");

    scanf(" %c", c);              //segmentation fault thrown here
    ck = c;

    if((int)c>=65 &&(int)c<=90)
        c = (int)c+32;

    while((ch = getc(fptr))){  
        if((int)ch>=65 && (int)ch<=90)   
            ch = (int)ch+32; 
        if(ch == EOF)    
            break; 
        else if(ch == c)    
            count+=1;
    }
    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter '%c'.",file1,count,ck);
    fclose(fptr);    
    return 0;    
}
```

but terminates while executing, what is the problem pls help

Comment: You'll someday discover (a) heeding elevated compiler warnings, and (b) checking the results of your IO operations rather than assuming they worked, are both skills worthy of fine-development.

Comment: use `getch();` before `return 0;`

Comment: I tried the same program and its working fine. Are you sure about file path you are entering? try @karthick code to check its opening the file or not. use `getch();` before return 1; in that code.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf(" %c",c);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
            ^ // Notice the ampersand &.
              // It is used to get the address which scanf() needs
```

---

**NOTE:** 
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Comment: yes sir i changed still  program is terminating. (after entering the character to be counted program is terminating)

Comment: @jhansigud, It will quit after printing the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is that indeed a problem? is quite common when starting to learn C/C++ that the app finishes and everything get closed making it looks like an error or failure...

the reason is that console applications once finisher return from their main method, the associated console window automatically closes. This behavior has nothing to do with what your app does or not, or if the app is working well or not.

To "correct" this simple add a pause just before the return statement in the main method

## Example:

```
....
   system("pause");  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: still didnot work sir .

Comment: `pause` is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

change the `scanf(" %c",c);` to `scanf(" %c",&c);` and check for the return value of fopen.

```
fptr=fopen(file1,"r");
if(fptr==NULL) {
   printf("failed to open file");
   return 1;
}
```